# Summing multiple (variable) columns with criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am trying to build a formula using multiple references to other cells. The easiest way to do this seems to be to build the formula as a string and then evaluate the string. However Excel no longer has an EVAL function.

More specifically, I have a table like so:

| Type | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 10 | 20 | 15 | 30 |
| Orange | 8 | 11 | 17 | 21 |
| Apple | 4 | 6 | 9 | 15 |
| Orange | 5 | 10 | 15 | 20 |

It's more complex, but this is the gist. I want to be able to sum multiple rows, from a given month through the end of the year for all of a type. I can't use a pivot table, as I'm using this in another table with other calculations. And I'd like to be able to change the month without breaking the formula.

I'm currently using sumproduct:
SUMPRODUCT( Tbl1[[Jan]:[Apr]] * (Tbl1[Type]="Apple") )

This works fine for January. But I'd like to be able to use the same formula for Feb, Mar, etc. I'd like to use another cell as a reference for the starting month. So in the above formula, change Jan to a reference to another cell. Unfortunately, Excel doesn't seem to recognize using a cell reference there.

To make it slightly more complicated, the table is in another tab.

I could build it as a string easily and evaluate it, but that ability *seems* to be gone.

Alternatively, is there another way to structure this?

Thanks!

Comment: "I can't use a pivot table". I expect you could, but there isn't enough detail here to show a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would flat the structure (through unpivot in powerquery), add numbers to months so it can be sorted/sliced easily and used the sumproduct with start month & end month

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to change the range, you just need to add another condition to select the months.

A simple solution you could do is to create a separate table for the month options, and pass the options into the `SUMPRODUCT` formula you already have.

Here are a couple examples.

- My table's name is `DATA` and the option table for the month names is named `OPTIONS_MONTHS`.

---

#### Example 1: Simple Options

- Option table for the months:

[image: Example1-A]

- With `Apr` added:

[image: Example1-B]

- Formula:

[image: Example1-C]

I just added an extra criteria to your formula:

```
       | =SUMPRODUCT( 
       |    DATA[[Jan]:[Apr]] * (DATA[Type]="Apple")    
Here > |    * (IFERROR(DATA[[#Headers],[Jan]:[Apr]]=TRANSPOSE(OPTIONS_MONTHS), FALSE)) 
       | )
```

---

#### Example 2: Include/Exclude Options

You can even spice it up a notch and include **all** of the months in the options table and use `booleans` to include/exclude the values so you don't have to re-type the month's name, and to prevent typos and some other errors.

- Include/Exclude field:

[image: Example2-A]

`Jul` is already set to `True` but the formula only selects the rows with `"Apple"`.

- Changed `Sep` to `True`:

[image: Example2-B]

`2` was added from the `Sep` column.

- Formula:

[image: Example2-C]

The formula is adjusted slightly here for the additional fields.

```
       | =SUMPRODUCT( 
       |    DATA[[Jan]:[Dec]] * (DATA[Type]="Apple")
Here > |    * (DATA[[#Headers],[Jan]:[Dec]]=
Here > |       TRANSPOSE(
Here > |         IF(OPTIONS_MONTHS[Include], OPTIONS_MONTHS[Months], FALSE))
Here > |       )
       | )
```

---

I would even recommend doing this with the `Type` field too and add some data validations.